# How to close div when div loses focus?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, blur, focusout

I made a simple plunkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/zNb65ErYH5HXgAQPOSM0?p=preview

I created a little datepicker I would like this to close itself when you focus out of it (focusout of datepicker) if I put blur on input I'm unable to use the datepicker, if I put focusout event on datepicker it doesn't works

I also tried:

```
angular.element(theCalendar).bind('blur', function () {
    $scope.hideCalendar();
});
```

but it doesn't work.

Any clue?

Comment: have you tried the ng-blur directive for inputs?

Comment: also, your plunker is full errors, please address these so others can help you.

Comment: @EliteOctagon sorry it was an old version of angular causing errors , fixed: http://plnkr.co/edit/zNb65ErYH5HXgAQPOSM0?p=preview

Comment: @sbaaang see update below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i know it probably is not the best practice or the best way to do this, but at the end i fixed and got what i need using this:

```
thisInput.bind('focus click', function bindingFunction() {

          isMouseOnInput = true;
          $scope.showCalendar();
          angular.element(theCalendar).triggerHandler('focus');
        });
        thisInput.bind('blur focusout', function bindingFunction() {

          isMouseOnInput = false;
        });

        angular.element(theCalendar).bind('mouseenter', function () {

          isMouseOn = true;
        });

        angular.element(theCalendar).bind('mouseleave', function () {

          isMouseOn = false;
        });

        angular.element($window).bind('click', function () {

          if (!isMouseOn && !isMouseOnInput) {

            $scope.hideCalendar();
          }
        });
```

I setted up some boolean vars to check where mouse is when you click the page and it works like a charm if you have some better solution that works , please let me know, but this actually fixed all.

I accept this as the answer but i thank all the guys on this page!

Answer (score 1):

this is because you are removing the item before you get a chance to do anything, here is a working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/mDfV9NLAQCP4l7wHdlfi?p=preview

just add a timeout:

```
thisInput.bind('blur', function () {
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.hideCalendar();
  }, 200);
});
```

have you considered using existing datepickers? like angularUI or angular-strap: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##datepickers

Update:

Not a complete solution, but should get you quite closer:

```
    angular.element($document[0].body).bind('click', function(e){
      console.log(angular.element(e.target), e.target.nodeName)
      var classNamed =  angular.element(e.target).attr('class');
      var inThing = (classNamed.indexOf('datepicker-calendar') > -1);
      if (inThing || e.target.nodeName === "INPUT") {
        console.log('in');
      } else {
        console.log('out');
          $timeout(function(){
            $scope.hideCalendar();
          }, 200);
      }
    });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/EbQl5xsCnG837rAEhBZh?p=preview

What you want to do then is to listen for a click on the page, and if the click is outside of the calendar, then close it, otherwise do nothing. The above only takes into account that you are clicking on something that has a class name which includes datepicker-calendar, you will need to adjust it so that clicking within the calendar doesn't close it as well.

Comment: i specified in the question that if i use blur on input i am unable to use the datepicker, try clicking on the year to choose an year ;)

Comment: i dont use angular-ui i dont need it sorry :)

Comment: i would like to hide datepicker when datepicker is on blur not input ;)

Comment: updated, see above. What you really should do is hide/show rather than add/remove the calendar

Comment: im sorry i probably explained bad, see the yellow bar on datepicker? clicking years u should be able to choose a new year from that yellow bar, but having blur on input it will close the datepicker before you can choose one :P that is the main problem

Comment: Updated, not a complete solution, but it works for when you click outside the calendar, now you just need to come up with extra logic which watches for clicks inside the calendar

Comment: +1 exactly! ive tryed it out, if i can get the yellow bar and datepickers paginations to work without datepicker to close itself ive done, thanks for the tip!!

Comment: i will try a little bit later ;)

Comment: I suggest you pick a common class name for everything inside the calendar, something long and complex that won't get repeated elsewhere, like a long randomly generated string and add it to each element inside the calendar, then when the click event fires, it will check for a class and close dependent on whether it finds that class. This is a bit of a hack, and there are better ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

How about closing on mouseout?

You need to cancel the close if you move to another div in the calendar though:

```
    //get the calendar as element
    theCalendar = element[0].children[1];

    // hide the calendar on mouseout
    var closeCalendarTimeout = null;
    angular.element(theCalendar).bind('mouseout', function () {
      if ( closeCalendarTimeout !== null )
        $timeout.cancel(closeCalendarTimeout);
      closeCalendarTimeout = $timeout(function () {
        $scope.hideCalendar();
      },250)
    });
    angular.element(theCalendar).bind('mouseover', function () {
      if ( closeCalendarTimeout === null ) return
      $timeout.cancel(closeCalendarTimeout);
      closeCalendarTimeout = null;
    });
```

**EDIT**

Adding a tabindex attribute to a div causes it to fire focus and blur events.

`, htmlTemplate = '<div class="datepicker-calendar" tabindex="0">' +`

```
angular.element(theCalendar).bind('blur', function () {
  $scope.hideCalendar();
});
```

Comment: i appriciated thanks, but sorry i want user to be able to see datepicker also if mouseout, i just want it to close on click ousidet of it :P

Comment: OK, then see the new suggestion in my answer (set the tabindex attribute on theCalendar).

Comment: @mameborn +1 for the cool tabindex attr i dint know, if only i could take the div to autofocus it will be definitive to use tabindex!!